# How do I handle ternary's in flow

Tags: flowtype

I am trying to figure out why a refinement is thrown out when using a ternary operator but not with an if else block.  See the following code snippet.

[handleError Fn](https://flowtype.org/try/#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)

Comment: hi @haasdev -- did my answer work for you?

Comment: That works great @thejohnbackes! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These aren't equivalent.

In the first function, your default case is to throw an Error. But in the second function, your default case is to set `error === res.message || res.statusText`.

What flow is saying here is, "hey, it's possible that res.message and res.statusText is undefined. If that's the case, then there's a conflict with `error: string`." To mimic the logic in the if-block example, you'd have to add error handling. [Here is a working example](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQBLAtgB1gJwC6gN4DOApjgCqzoDKOAhjsQL6iRayqgDkAdMIXQ04BuRIhwBPdMVAAlYoUwA7EmUnSAvAUShQqeYVoBzYgC5QAfn5ZkiwwBptofvQCuhM4peoARsSwOdZxw3MmIADxwzSxxrW0RGEURIF0UAYxxkWEVQAAtaRQATaGIAUSw2LAAKFyxoMysbe1AseTM5BSyVNQBKMwA3WGQCrR1ivD8K+pjGkR1kSFBKlsJuILdQdU3QABZtgAZukZ1QCewNrip9TOyyNGJYFxxhR2ZiaBJQecXl7j1CA2Mh3wjgAkKcsOcfn8AcRZqBXu9pF8lvJVgIQuEcEDHDpwZDUWtCKEInCER9gcdQDgcmx4KBFMQ6WUKpVuqTHI4SORKDR6MRKvhwYw2fFRMk0hksrl8kVSuVsNValNYk1lm15EoulJeqABkMjsiAIRQ-RGaQAH3NoGNBPRRMx2J0IOptPpjNAzIVIp0jEcqU643lWGVjXxK0JGy2uz2FlBnEu-2uoFuegeT1AJlBJv+ZtAluattc9pJokCpAo1AE-MFQeFIl9QA).

```
function handleError(url: string, res: ResponseType): void {
  let error: string;
  if (!res.message || !res.statusText) {
    throw new Error();
  }
  const error: string = res.status === 440 ?
    'Session Timeout' :
    res.message || res.statusText;

  setTopState({error});
}
```

The documentation describes this under "[Refinement Invalidations](https://flowtype.org/en/docs/lang/refinements/#refinement-invalidations)".